# Is it possible for creating separate resource files for Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources

I create my solution by using Asp.net MVC pattern which has at least 4 projects.

1. **App.Models**
2. **App.Globalization**
3. **App.Controllers**

   - References : App.Model and App.Globalization
4. **App.Views**

   - References : App.Model, App.Globalization and App.Controller

I need to create .net resources file for using by both App.Controller project and App.Views project. First, I try to create App.Globalization project for sharing resources. But I need to save resx file in App_Globalization folder in App.Views project and save designer.cs file(generated code of resx file) in App.Globalization project because it's easy to modify & save data in resources file.

Is it possible for creating separated resouce files for Asp.net MVC without using custom tool(s) or post-build command?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy by using the following step.

1. Add resource file to **App_GlobalResources** folder in **App.Views** project.
2. Set **Build Action** property of **designer.cs** file to **None**.
3. Unload **App.Globalization** project.
4. Edit **App.Globalization** project by adding the following code.

> ```
> <Project>
>     <ItemGroup>
>         <Compile Include="..\App.Views\App_GlobalResources\WebApp.designer.cs">
>             <Link>WebApp.designer.cs</Link>
>         </Compile>
>     </ItemGroup>
> </Project>
> ```